# uninitialized constant error in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm trying to test my mailer using Capybara and FactoryGirl along with RSpec. I ended up having the error:

```
/spec/mailers/password_resets_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant PasswordResets (NameError)
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

My PasswordReset resource doesn't contain a model. Maybe it's somehow related with this?

**spec/mailers/password_resets_spec.rb**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe PasswordResets do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    user = FactoryGirl(:user)
    visit login_path
    click_link "Forgot your password?"
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    click_button "Reset Password"
  end
end
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end


  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end


end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to describe is the description of that example group. You can put PasswordResets in a string.

```
describe 'PasswordResets' do
```

Comment: I've spent an hour. Can you realize? Thanks)

Comment: It can be a description, or the class name of what you're actually testing. Usually for feature specs it's a description, but for everything else it's the class name.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two problems here.

1) `PasswordResets` might not be the correct class name of your mailer. Typically it would end in `Mailer` and be something like `PasswordResetMailer`. But if it is actually `PasswordResets`, then we go to 2).

2) If you're in a Rails app, your spec files need to `require "rails_helper"`, not `spec_helper`. This will set up Rails, with all the right autoloading, to find the right constants. This will also affect the loading of the User model inside the spec, and other things as well.